# None value in dataframe columns of strings, error in class

Tags: python, pandas, class, oop

I'm new in python and i'm trying do a python class to transform and clean a telephone numbers, dataframe column.

The error appears when i call my class and the class receive a none value from dataframe line.

My Class

```
class Tel(object):
    '''Classe que invalida telefones não válidos'''

    def __init__(self, phone):
        self.phone = phone
        self.phone_tratado = self.phone = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', self.phone)
        self.ddd_valido = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
                          21, 22, 24, 27, 28,
                          31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38,
                          41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49,
                          51, 53, 54, 55,
                          61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,
                          71, 73, 74, 75, 77, 79,
                          81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89,
                          91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]


    def valida_telefone(self):

        if int(self.phone_tratado[:2]) in self.ddd_valido:
            # ddd valido
            if self.phone_tratado is None: # nulo
                return None

            if len(self.phone_tratado) == 10:
                if self.phone_tratado[2] in ['0', '1']: #fixoinvalido
                    return None
                if self.phone_tratado[2] in ['2', '3', '4', '5']:#fixo valido
                    return self.phone_tratado
                else:# celular, ajustar
                    return self.phone_tratado[:2] + '9' + self.phone_tratado[2:]
            elif len(self.phone_tratado) == 11: #celular
                if self.phone_tratado[2] == '9' and self.phone_tratado[3] in ['6', '7', '8', '9']:# celular valido
                    return self.phone_tratado
                else:
                    return None
            else:# qtde invalida
                return None
        else:# ddd invalido
            return None

My example Dataframe: NR_T
## +-------+------+
## |INDEX  |NR_TEL|
## +-------+------+
## |10     | 1    |
## |1      | 2    |
## |7      | None |
## +-------+------+
```

My Calls:

```
Tel(df_2.loc[10,'NR_TEL']).valida_telefone()
```

Working fine

```
Tel(df_2.loc[7,'NR_TEL']).valida_telefone()
```

Error: Expected Atring or bytes like object

How can i do my class claen too None values? I mean, accpet none values to transform after

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening when `self.phone` is `None`, and you run `re.sub('[^0-9]', '', self.phone)` in your `__init__` method. `re.sub` requires a string-like object, not `None`.

One option would be to provide a default value for `self.phone`, e.g.:

```
def __init__(self, phone):
    if phone is None:
        # use "0" or some other default value
        phone = "0" 
    self.phone = phone
    ...
```

But a more Pythonic solution would be to require a string-like object and raise an exception if it's not. Then, you'd need to deal with those `None` values before using your class:

```
def __init__(self, phone):
    if isinstance(phone, str):
    # or use, if Python 2.x:
    # if isinstance(phone, basestring):
        raise Exception("Phone number must be a string")
    self.phone = phone
    ...
```

Then deal with the `None`'s separately, e.g., by filtering them out:

```
df_2_notnull = df_2[pd.notnull(df_2["NR_TEL"])]
```

This will just cover the `__init__` method. Note that your `valida_telefone` method requires `phone_tratado[:2]` to successfully cast to an `int`. If, for example, the phone number were an empty string, this would raise a different exception.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick read of your problem and I think you should probably test if the value is `None` before testing `if int(self.phone_tratado[:2]) in self.ddd_valido`

So it woul look something like this

```
def valida_telefone(self):
    if self.phone_tratado is None: # nulo
            return None
    else:

        if int(self.phone_tratado[:2]) in self.ddd_valido:
            # ddd valido
        ...
```